# Trying to identify a sci-fi story I listened to several years ago featuring a far future human that can adjust his body to any alien environment

Tags: story-identification, audio-book, podcast

Several years ago I listened to either a podcast or audiobook of a story about a future human that is stranded on an alien planet.  He can adjust his lungs to breath the toxic atmosphere and also intuitively alter his body to survive in any alien environment.  It starts out rather similar to Robinson Crusoe with him adjusting to the planet and surviving in solitude but soon he discovers another being like himself on the beach that's been mostly devoured by alien sea creatures.  He nurses this scrap of human back to what winds up being a human woman with abilities the same as his and he must now adjust to living with another person.  I got interrupted at that point in the story and never finished it.

Comment: Details are scanty here.  **King of Argent** mostly matches what you have.  A [previous question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/167439/30870) has more details that you might recognize.  I don't remember the protagonist having to nurse the woman from the brink of death, but it's been a while since I read it.  I don't know if it has an audiobook version.